# IE Bug - content flows over image!

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My friends has just asked me to have a look at his site in IE and I found that the content is going over his top image!

http://www.skiphire.org/

The site has been created in wordpress so im note sure on how he has gone about making the page!

Can anyone point him in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: which IE? there's more than one.

Comment: I can't see this problem and I suspect you've just asked this so you can post yet another spam link.

Comment: i am not spamming! if u use any IE browser in perticular IE6 or 7 you will see that the text goes over the main image!

Comment: Mate, Ian is one of my employees and I told him to use StackOverflow to help him with problems he's having difficulty with. How about you do some work instead of running around accusing people of spamming?

Comment: Maybe better to post this type of question to http://doctype.com/?

Comment: Totally disagree. Web/CSS development falls within the context of StackOverflow as you will see if you look through all the other questions in the same topic.

Comment: @Charlie: The problem does not appear in IE8 "native mode", but appears when using "compatibility mode", which suggests to me that the problem appears in IE7 (and possibly 6). @Nathan: Who are you to tell anybody "to do some work"?

Comment: @Charlie: Did you even look at the link before accusing him of spamming?  It's a site that offers construction site waste removal.  Not exactly the type of company that's going to go around spamming programing forums.  +1 from me to counteract people that don't check their facts before making accusations.

Comment: @Jason If he's going to make an inflammatory comment like that, he should expect a similarly-toned retort.

Comment: @Eric @Nathan Guys I saw a question earlier for a PPI claims website which was similar and Ian had asked a load of not very clear questions with that same link and looked like spam. Obviously I'm wrong though, so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the image with ALIGN="RIGHT", put the image as the background on div:contentmiddle - top left no-repeat.  Add padding-top:160px to the div, too.

Also, that image is 169 pixels tall, getting scaled down.  Crop the image to 160px tall, you'll save bandwidth and the image will look nicer.